# Is it possible to do combined testing of mobile apps and web portal using Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android

Is it possible to do combined testing of mobile apps and web portal using Appium?
For example : If user performs an action in mobile app and I need to check whether it reflects in web portal. Is this possible by writing a single test case in appium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that you can use selenium for testing web application and appium for mobile testing. If you are using Apppium using Java then you can do this from the same script/test case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!